# Fetch youtube channels having content revolving around a certain topic

Tags: javascript, python, api, youtube

How do I fetch the names of youtube channels having content revolving around a certain topic?

```py
fetchChannels("cats")
```

should fetch channel names revolving around cat vidoes.

Before asking this question I've checked the youtube API but didn't found anything useful.

How would I go about doing this preferably in JavaScript or Python?

Comment: Use the YouTube Data API for search videos about "cats" (*in your example*) and filter those results by its name and/or description.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  link below and fetch the data.
You will get the channel by any name

[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=channel&maxResults=100&key=[api-key]&q=cat](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=channel&maxResults=100&key=%5Bapi-key%5D&q=cat)